# How to log request and response body in WebFlux using MDC + Logbook

Tags: logging, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, mdc

I have a Spring Boot application, a reactive service which calls external systems via WebClient. I also have some non-reactive services. There is already implemented logging using `MDC` + `Logbook` for `Feign` clients. It's highly desirable to reuse existing classes or at least make log records look the same as non-reactive services logs.

```
RESPONSE_CODE=200, RESPONSE_HEADERS=[transfer-encoding:"chunked"], METHOD=POST, REQUEST_QUERY={}, REQUEST_BODY=FluxMap, RESPONSE_BODY=, REQUEST_PATH=/ping, REQUEST_HEADERS=[Session:"11111abcd", Content-Type:"application/json", ..., Content-Length:"37"], TYPE=INREQ
```

Current logs look like that. Problematic parts are `REQUEST_BODY=FluxMap` and `RESPONSE_BODY=`

I managed to log body using `wiretap()` on WebClient, but it's not customisable, so it doesn't suit.

For reference, I used sample code from this [article](http://ttddyy.github.io/mdc-with-webclient-in-webmvc/)
which I found in this Github [discussion](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1985)

I've tried different approaches: using `ExchangeFilterFunction` and `WebFilter` + `ServerHttpRequestDecorator` (and other decorators) where I try to get body from `DataBuffer`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Add this dependency

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
>    <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-webflux-autoconfigure</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Pass `Logbook` object when you create a `WebClient`

> ```
> private WebClient getWebClient(Logbook logbook) {
>     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
>             .doOnConnected(connection -> {
>                 connection.addHandlerLast(new LogbookClientHandler(logbook));
>             });
>
>     return WebClient.builder()
>             .baseUrl(myUrl)
>             .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
>             .build();
> }
> ```